# What would have happened if Esdeath hadn't drunk all the demon extract?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

In Akame Ga Kill! I'm wondering why Esdeath drank all the demon extract.
If she hadn't drunk the whole thing, could someone else have gained the power?

Can an Imperial Arms have 2 users at the same time?

Comment: I think as long as there's another one who's compatible with the demon extract, he/she can use its power. But since Esdeath holds the power of the demon extract and only one can use a Teigu, I guess the remaining extract won't have an effect since there is already an owner unless Esdeath dies. Just a guess.

Comment: I'm under the impression you can't survive unless you drink the entire thing.

Comment: I think the urge to drink it all proves compatibility as to be compatible you have to like it and gulbing down a drink shows that.

Answer (score 1):

Esdeath's near-broken ice-making abilities come from the fact that she drank the whole goblet of demon extract. If she hadn't drunk the whole thing, her powers would probably not be so profound.

She would probably have to be near external supplies of water like her snake-ring-wielding partner to make ice and use it.